# Where did LoaderService go?

Tags: anglesharp

Upgrading AngleSharp from 0.9.6 to 0.9.9 I have this line of code no longer compiling:

```
return configuration.With(LoaderService(new[] { requester }));
```

It complains that `LoaderService` does not exist in the current context. So what happened to `LoaderService`? Is there a replacement? Does it still exist but just somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Sorry for being late to the party, but even though you may have solved your problem someone else is having a hard time figuring it out.

`LoaderService` was essentially just a helper to create a loader. But having a service for anything creating a little thing would be overkill and not scale much. Also AngleSharp.Core would need to define all these. So, instead a generic mechanism was introduced, which allows registering such "creator services" via `Func<IBrowsingContext, TService>`.

However, to solve your piece of code I guess the following line would do the trick:

```
return configuration.WithDefaultLoader(requesters: requester);
```

This registers the default loader creator services (one for documents, one for resources inside documents) with the default options (options involve some middleware etc.).

Under the hood (besides some other things) the following is happening:

```
// just one example, config.Filter is created based on the passed in options
return configuration.With<IDocumentLoader>(ctx => new DocumentLoader(ctx, config.Filter));
```